# How do i fix command not found when running heroku local?

Tags: heroku

How do i fix the heroku error?

I am getting below when running heroku local. Any idea -

heroku local
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format

7:53:20 AM web.1    |  /bin/sh: leaderboard-web: command not found

[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT

7:53:20 AM worker.1 |  /bin/sh: leaderboard-worker: command not found

7:53:20 AM web.1    Exited with exit code null

7:53:20 AM worker.1 Exited with exit code null

Below is my Procfile content -

web: leaderboard-web

worker: leaderboard-worker

release: ./release-tasks.sh

Below is the heroku ps output -

heroku ps

=== web (Free): leaderboard-web (1)
web.1: up 2022/04/07 07:50:01 +0600 (~ 7m ago)

]=== worker (Free): leaderboard-worker (1)
worker.1: up 2022/04/07 07:50:01 +0600 (~ 7m ago)

I am running a golang application in macos

Comment: Well, does `leaderboard-web` exist? Have you compiled your code?

Comment: cmd/leaderboard-web/main.go

Comment: I don't use Go, but that looks like the name of a _source_ file. Your `Procfile` tells Heroku to run `leaderboard-web`. Can you run `leaderboard-web` yourself? If you can't run it, how can Heroku? You'll need to build your code and make sure you can run `./leaderboard-web`, then try `heroku local` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procfile

```
web: go run cmd/leaderboard-web/main.go
worker: go run cmd/leaderboard-worker/main.go
release: ./release-tasks.sh
```

solves the issue